# How long should I wait before flagging a new post?

Tags: discussion, flags

I often watch the new feed of questions for my preferred tags, and when I see something wrong (like an answer of very low quality, or a question that is too broad for Stack Overflow), I will flag as soon as I see it.

But often, some minutes after I cast the flag and before it is reviewed by a moderator, the post I flagged is edited. This causes my flag to either be "declined" or "disputed" (which is right).

So my question is, is it right to rapidly flag a post, or should I put the page aside and wait a few minutes to see if the post is going to be edited before flagging?

Comment: If it's spam, flag as soon as possible. You could comment if you think it might be salvageable by the OP.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are touchy-feely enough to "smell" when a question might be improved and/or you have the patience to talk the poster through it in the comments, you might want to try that first. However, nobody expects that of you, so when you come across bad content, flag it as such, regardless of timing. We're all busy people, we can't wait around whether something may or may not improve before acting.

[image: an unattended bag]

Comment: I don't consider a bag with an elephant next to it "unattended". It's clearly *his* bag.

Comment: Hmm, this is actually a pretty good metaphor for how flagging works on Stack Overflow. You flag a post because an elephant is blocking the aisleway for other passengers, and your flag gets declined because the actual problem was the unattended bag. Doh!

Comment: @Cody He's not blocking the aisle, he's *attending the bag!* Flag declined.

Comment: Yet, an elephant going to the circus on a commuter train by itself does not qualify as unusual behavior? We don't see many elephants riding commuter trains 'round these parts.

Comment: Additionaly, if the OP is editing a on hold question it goes automaticly into the reopen queue.

Comment: @deceze What about the fact that the elephant is facing the wrong way?

Comment: @matt There's no rule against facing the wrong way. Flag declined.